# JSlint ignoring globals set inside .jshintrc file - used in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, jslint, jshint

I am trying to use jshint and jslint.I am using custom `.jshintrc` file and add few of my global variables and functions into globals inside `.jshintrc` as below.

```
{


  // Environments
  "browser"       : true,     // Web Browser (window, document, etc)
  "browserify"    : false,    // Browserify (node.js code in the browser)
  "couch"         : false,    // CouchDB
  "devel"         : true,     // Development/debugging (alert, confirm, etc)
  "dojo"          : false,    // Dojo Toolkit
  "jasmine"       : false,    // Jasmine
  "jquery"        : true,    // jQuery
  "mocha"         : true,     // Mocha
  "mootools"      : false,    // MooTools
  "node"          : true,    // Node.js
  "nonstandard"   : false,    // Widely adopted globals (escape, unescape, etc)
  "phantom"       : false,    // PhantomJS
  "prototypejs"   : false,    // Prototype and Scriptaculous
  "qunit"         : false,    // QUnit
  "rhino"         : false,    // Rhino
  "shelljs"       : false,    // ShellJS
  "typed"         : false,    // Globals for typed array constructions
  "worker"        : false,    // Web Workers
  "wsh"           : false,    // Windows Scripting Host
  "yui"           : false,    // Yahoo User Interface

  "globals": {
    "swal": true,
    "testvar1":true,
    "testfunction1":true,
    "testfunction2":true,
    "testvar2":true,
    "console":true,
    "$":true

  }

}
```

I am getting following errors

```
JSLint:Undeclared console
JSLint:Undeclared $
```

When I add `/*gloabls console */` in same file it is working fine.How to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Why would JSLint (with an L) care about the configuration file of JSHint (with a H)?

Comment: I thought both are some how inter connected is there separate config file for jsLint

Comment: AFAIK, no. See http://jslint.com/help.html for the documentation.